# How to call web-api controller from mvc5 project

Tags: angularjs, asp.net-mvc-5

I wanted to call web-api controller from mvc5 web project using angularjs.here important thing is that my mvc5 and web-api is separate project.

**below is my  **edited code** angularjs controller functionality**

```
//following is our application module.ngGrid is the angular grid that we need to use to display data.
var categoryApp = angular.module('categoryApp', ['ngGrid']);
var url = 'http://localhost:8053/api/Category';


//the factory object for the webAPI call.
categoryApp.factory('categoryRepository', ['$resource',
    function ($resource) {
        return $resource('/api/Category');
    }
]);

//controller   
categoryApp.controller('categoryCtrl', ['$scope', 'categoryRepository', 
    function($scope, categoryRepository) {
        $scope.categoryData = categoryRepository.get() 
        //or .query() if it returns an array

        //if you need to manipulate the data after retrieval:
        categoryRepository.get().$promise.then(function(data){
            $scope.categoryData = data;
        })

        $scope.setScope = function (obj, action) {

            $scope.action = action;
            $scope.New = obj;
        }

        $scope.gridOptions = {
            data: 'categoryData',
            showGroupPanel: true,
            columnDefs: [{ field: 'Name', displayName: 'Name', width: '15%' },
                { field: 'Description', displayName: 'Description', width: '15%' },

            ]
        };
    }
])
```

the problem is that web-api is not calling through above code
please let me know soon how to resolve this issue.

Answer (score 0):

I would refactor your `categoryRepository` to be a `resource`:

```
categoryApp.factory('categoryRepository', ['$resource',
    function($resource) {
        return $resource('/api/Category');
    }
])
```

You can then use this in your controller:

```
categoryApp.controller('categoryCtrl', ['$scope', 'categoryRepository', 
    function($scope, categoryRepository) {
        $scope.categoryData = categoryRepository.get() 
        //or .query() if it returns an array

        //if you need to manipulate the data after retrieval:
        categoryRepository.get().$promise.then(function(data){
             $scope.categoryData = data;
        })
    }
])
```

In order to use `$resource`, you will need to include the resource module in your app (you can find instructions on the [angular docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngResource))

Comment: we have followed your instruction but still facing same issue. please suggest....

Comment: The issue is most likely on the server side of your application. Have you tried to inspect the response received by `GET /api/Category` in the Network panel of your browser devtools?

Comment: http://localhost:8053/api/Category/ is returning data. but from above edited code its not calling.

Comment: No errors in the console? Have you tried `console.debug(data)` in the `.then` callback?